# Single CAB for pocket pc and smartphone versions of same application

Tags: windows, compact-framework, mobile, pocketpc, smartphone

Is it possible to create a single cab that will allow me to package both PocketPc and Smartphone version of Windows Mobile application?  What I would like is to be able to check during installation if device is pocket pc or smartphone and then install appropriate versions.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but Microsoft does have a sample project that demonstrates the creation of a container CAB file, which houses multiple CAB files within it. I would imagine you could add in the logic required to detect the mobile platform and execute the appropriate installer.

Multiple CAB Install @ MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx

In practice, we've always built separate CAB files and, using the mechanisms provided by [CEAppMgr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158696.aspx), [define a single "entry" in the Add/Remove Programs dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158614.aspx) of ActiveSync/WMDC that references our platform-specific CABs.

Another avenue would be [creating a custom Setup.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) file as part of your CAB, which provides you the opportunity to perform actions before and after your CAB installation.